# ssh through port 443 on gitlab not working

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to use port 443 to push and pull my gitlab repository since my port 22 has been blocked (reference: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/)

I have given below my config file that i created (i created a new ssh key that I updated in my gitlab profile - Note: I did not add the server key as a deploy key, rather, I just added it in my profile)

my config file:

```
Host gitlab.com
        Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
        User gitlabusername
        Port 443
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I keep getting the following error:

permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Could the error be because of something other than the ssh key?

Regards,
Galeej

Comment: Do you have a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: no.  We are currently using https instead of ssh.  We still haven't figured it out yet :(

Comment: I found out that ssh works for me over cable but not over wifi

Comment: we tried both.  Didnt help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just configured it and it's working well for me.

In your config file you need to use the private key `id_rsa` for authenticating not the public one `id_rsa.pub`

```
Host gitlab.com
  Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
  User git
  Port 443
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You may test the connection using using this command `ssh -T -p 443 git@altssh.gitlab.com`.

*Make sure that you already added the public key `id_rsa.pub` to your GitLab account as [described here](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair).*

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: If you get any permissions issues running on and amazon ec2 box one may want to `chmod 600 config`